# Unable to find row with "=" operation that certainly exists

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The following statement returns empty set.

```
SELECT id,field_DOMid FROM korektura WHERE field_DOMid = 'vyznam-1284--vyklad_vyznamu' ORDER BY cts DESC LIMIT 1;
```

But look at the results of LIKE (the value is there):

[image: Conole output]

can any one suggest what can cause such a behavior? Is it the MySQL server problem, collation problem? (we use custom collation defined for UTF8 charset in collations/index.xml)

There is no trailing whitespaces:

```
mysql> SELECT field_DOMid, CHAR_LENGTH(field_DOMid),  CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(field_DOMid)) FROM korektura WHERE id=27580;
 +-----------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| field_DOMid                 | CHAR_LENGTH(field_DOMid) | CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(field_DOMid)) |
+-----------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| vyznam-1284--vyklad_vyznamu |                       27 |                             27 |
+-----------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What is more, the MySQL documentation says:

> All MySQL collations are of type PADSPACE. This means that all CHAR, VARCHAR, and TEXT values in MySQL are compared without regard to any trailing spaces.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the value start with a whitespace?

Comment: Unfortunately it is probably not the case. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Let's see `LENGTH()` (which is byte-count) and `HEX()`.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE korektura`.

Comment: What version of mysql or mariadb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone runs into such problem, the solution in my case was to rebuild indexes (tables):

```
mysqldump db_name > dump.sql
mysql db_name < dump.sql
```

or use other methotds described here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rebuilding-tables.html

Comment: `OPTIMIZE TABLE tablename` is a simpler way to rebuild the indexes.

Comment: I wanted to rebuild all the 172 tables, therefore the `mysqldump` solution.

Answer (score 0):

the only reason i can think of for this is if you have an empty space or a line break character preceding the "vyznam". try checking for that.

Comment: Unfortunately it is probably not the case. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query for debugging:

```
SELECT field_DOMid, LENGTH(field_DOMid), LENGTH(TRIM(field_DOMid)) , CHAR_LENGTH(field_DOMid),  CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(field_DOMid)) FROM korektura WHERE id=27580;
```

In case `LENGTH()` returns more than 27, it means that the first character is probably encoded with a two-byte character (which is legal in UTF-8). So if you want to match it against a literal string, you have to [convert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-convert.html) it first:

```
SELECT id,field_DOMid FROM korektura WHERE field_DOMid = convert('vyznam-1284--vyklad_vyznamu' using utf8) ORDER BY cts DESC LIMIT 1;
```